# How to debug conflicting dependencies in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, conflict, transitive-dependency

When I build my Maven-managed Java project, two versions of the same artifact are installed into the build (a war file).  I am pretty sure that it doesn't matter, but the artifact in question is **com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations** versions **2.7.3 and 2.9.7**.

When I run **mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose**, there are no occurrences of **jackson-annotations:2.7.3**, indeed, there are no occurrences of the string **2.7.3** anywhere in the resulting output.

My question is, how do I proceed to debug this problem?  I believed that the **dependency:tree** goal would give me the full set of transitive dependencies.  Is this belief correct?  If not, what would?

For the record, on my local machine the new version of the library is found and everything works, but when deployed to another machine the deployment is broken because that machine finds the old version of the library.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>something</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.48</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>a</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.34</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>b</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.36</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- Jersey -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey Test Framework -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>
            org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers
        </groupId>
        <artifactId>
            jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2
        </artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>myrepository</id>
        <name>My repository name</name>
        <url>myrepositoryurl</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>.</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>pom.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I would expect dependency:tree to find this. How are you building your war? Can you add a simplified pom which illustrates the problem to your question?

Comment: @tgdavies  I simplified the pom and added it to the question.  What are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Well.

This is embarrassing.

This had nothing to do with Maven or its dependency computation.  Rather I had a WEB-INF/lib folder in my project, which contained the conflicting libraries, and which was being merged into the .war file at build time.

Thanks everyone for looking at this and trying to help with a chimerical problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can without debugging just expanding all you project dependencies and looking by the one that you are look
[image]

then on that dependency you can exclude some inner libraries in you pom.xml ie:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-core</artifactId>
        <version>${utransactions.core}</version>
<!-- this exclusion -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I did that (obviously).  That view agrees with **dependency:tree**.  The library that is included in the war file is not mentioned in that view of the tree either.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the [`dependency:tree` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) in such a way that you ensure it is using the latest version of its own innards (as you can any Maven plugin you can run from the command line):

```sh
$ mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree
```

(In Ancient Times™ the `dependency:tree` goal's dependency resolution algorithm may not have matched that actually used by Maven itself.  It might be that you are using an ancient version of the plugin unknowingly.)

Comment: Interesting comment.  How do I determine the version of maven's dependency resolution algorithm, and the version of the plug in that matches it?

Comment: Honestly, just use the latest version of the `maven-dependency-plugin`, which, as of this writing, is 3.1.2.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that, and got exactly the same results.

Comment: I see you are also using a very, very old version of the `maven-war-plugin`.  Perhaps it is using the old dependency resolution algorithm as well.  Try replacing `2.6` with `3.3.1`.